# The percent sign in R

Tags: r

I recently read some source code for a R package called 'pathifier'. In the source code, it uses the percent sign.

```
if (0 %in% xs) {
si <- NULL
cat(file = logfile, append = TRUE, "skipping pathway ", 
i, " (0 in xs)\n")
}
```

What does `%in%` mean in this function? Does it just mean the regular 'in'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `in` reserved word can only be used in `for` loops. The `%in%` function is different. As noted in the documentation at `?"%in%"`, is defined as:

```
"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

So, it is essentially `match`. In English, `x %in% y` returns a vector of `logical` of the same length as x, with `TRUE` every time the corresponding element of `x` exists at least once in `y`.

The reason why there are `%` around it is to mark it as a "infix" operator. (I don't know if that is the exact term.)

Comment: The correct R terminology (not withstanding Tyler's somewhat bizarre position) is "special operator".

Comment: @DWin The [section in the docs](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Special-operators) indeed calls them "special operators", but notes that special operators are used to define "infix operators". Perhaps the "special operator" term refers to the `%`, and the "infix operator" term refers to the operator defined by the "special operator". But maybe not.

Comment: I do not understand the resistance being displayed to the term 'special'. The other place in R Reference is in the operators listing: `%x% Special binary operators, x can be replaced by any valid name`.

Comment: @nograpes I have to agree with DWin. The docs explicitly defines special operators as having *the form of a string of characters delimited by the ‘%’ character*.

Comment: `infix operators` are operators between 2 variables ie: `(a + b)`.  A `postfix operator` is `(a,b)+` and `prefix operator` is `+(a,b)`.  Given that definition, `%in%` is indeed an `infix operator`.  However, R documentation takes special note of operators with `%` as "special operators".  So both are correct.

Answer (score 9):

The useR is given the capacity to create new infix functions and the dispatch mechanism will recognize functions whose names begin and end with `%`. Say you wanted to make an infix operator that replicated a value n number of times:

```
 `%rep%` <- function(x,y) rep(x,y)
  10 %rep% 5
  # [1] 10 10 10 10 10
```

Another example of doing such will be found on the help page for ?match which discusses `%in%` as well as demonstrates how to make an `%w/o%` infix operator. The section in the R Language Reference that describes this is 10.3.4: "Special operators".