# Subsetting geojson data with R

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, geojson, ropensci

I have a geojson file of state boundaries [that I obtained from here](http://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/). In particular I'm using [the 20m US States Data](http://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json)

I'm trying to subset the data so that I can use leaflet to map only certain states.  I can subset a single state using:

```
states <- geojsonio::geojson_read("gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json", what = "sp")
az <- subset(states, NAME == "Arizona")
```

This method does not seem to work for selecting multiple states though:

```
swStates <- subset(states, NAME == c("Arizona", "Nevada", "New Mexico"))
```

Selecting multiple states usually results in only one or two states being selected, or none at all.  Is there a different method I can use to subset this data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `%in%` rather than `==`

```
cities <- geojsonio::us_cities
TwoCities <- subset(cities, name %in% c("Seattle WA", "San Francisco CA"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm relatively new to R, and this is my first time working with geojson data.  Is  %in% unique to this type of data?

Comment: %in% can be used widely for 'is a member of'. Gory details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554007/the-percent-sign-in-r

Answer (score 3):

Not to take away from the accepted answer, just throwing out an option if you want to get nerdy with JSON.

I have a pkg in dev that tries to help filter raw GeoJSON itself using `jqr` package (so no need to convert to a `sp` object and use `subset`)

```
devtools::install_github("ropenscilabs/geofilter")
library(geofilter)
library(leaflet)

url <- "http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json"
curl::curl_download(url, destfile = (f <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")))
ariz <- sifter(readLines(f), NAME == Arizona)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(ariz) %>%
  setView(-112, 34, zoom = 7)
```

can't currently do many matches at the time (e.g., `NAME %in% c(Arizona, Nevada, New Mexico)`)

Answer (score 3):

Also not taking away from the accepted answer, but here is an alternative approach.

I'm using `library(geojsonsf)` to read the GeoJSON directly into an `sf` object. From there you can subset it as per any `data.frame` (and do other spatial operations on it using `library(sf)`)

```
url <- "http://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json"

## use library(geojsonsf) to convert into an sf object
sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(url)

library(dplyr)
library(sf)

sf %>%
    filter(NAME %in% c("Arizona", "Nevada", "New Mexico"))


# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 5 fields
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -120.0057 ymin: 31.3323 xmax: -103.002 ymax: 42.00025
# epsg (SRID):    4326
# proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# CENSUSAREA      GEO_ID LSAD       NAME STATE                       geometry
# 1   113594.1 0400000US04         Arizona    04 POLYGON ((-112.5386 37.0006...
# 2   121298.1 0400000US35      New Mexico    35 POLYGON ((-105.998 32.00233...
# 3   109781.2 0400000US32          Nevada    32 POLYGON ((-114.0466 40.1169...
```