# How to Filter GeoJSON Data by FIPS or State when Data is Nested

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, geojson

I am trying to filter US the county level shape data set by either FIPS or state.  The original data set can be found [here](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_5m.zip).  However, I am using a version that has been somewhat cleaned by plotly.

I am able to read the data into R with the following code.

```
url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'

county_data <- geojsonio::geojson_read(url)
```

I have a list of FIPS `fips <- c(20129, 19139, 17167, 19057, 17141)`, and I can also generate a list of states where the FIPS originate from `states <- c('IL', 'IA', 'IN')`.

I've been able to identify the indices of the necessary boundaries by doing the following.

```
necessary_values = c()
for (i in 1:3221) {
  if(county_data$features[[i]]$id %in% fips) {
    necessary_values <- c(necessary_values, i)
  }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble sub-setting the `county_data` because the geojson is structured such that it produces a list of length 2 with attributes `type` and `features`.  `type` is just `chr` and `features` is a list of length 3,221 where each element has the geometry data as well as an `id` attribute which is the FIPS value.

I've already considered the solutions posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145379/subsetting-geojson-data-with-r), but they do not help because of the structure of the geojson.

Should I be using a different approach? or am I on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using the package **sf** and **tidyverse**-style code, here's a suggestion.

This code reads the geojson into a simple feature collection, then shows how you can filter all counties in state number "04" (looks like Arizona) and plot them.

If you don't want to plot them, of course, just delete those lines :)

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'

county_data <- sf::read_sf(url)

county_data %>%
  filter(STATE == "04") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

If you want to filter for specific county ids, you're on the right track. This code  sets up a vector of fips, then filters the original data to create a new sf object with only those fips. (Then plots them again, for good measure.)

```
fips <- c(20129, 19139, 17167, 19057, 17141)

county_data_subset <- county_data %>%
  filter(id %in% fips)

county_data_subset %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, when I attempt to use `dplyr::filter`, I get the error `Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Hi Max, that error looks like R is using `stats::filter()` instead of `dplyr::filter()`.

Two suggestions:
1. Call it directly, like so:
`county_data %>%  dplyr::filter(STATE == "04")`

2. Make sure you attach the package `dplyr` first, with `library(dplyr)`.

Let me know if this doesn't work.